# Camera intent throws Null Pointer Exception in Sony Phones

Tags: android, sony, android-camera-intent

I'm intenting `Camera Intent` which works perfectly on other devices except `Sony C2305` [4.2.2]. Tested on 4.2.2 Emulator which works perfectly fine.

Following is the snippet . I uses to  call `Camera Intent`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 getImagePath();
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

---

```
 public void getImagePath()
        {
            File imageDirectory =null;
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
            {
                imageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/ABC");
            }
            else
            {
                imageDirectory = new File(SmartConsultant.getApplication().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
            }
            imageDirectory.mkdirs();
            File tempFile = new File(imageDirectory, getVideoName()+ AppConstants.EXTENSION); //AppConstants.Extension is .jpg and getVideoName to fetch name of file as per current sys time.
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( tempFile );
            currentFileUri = outputFileUri;
        }
```

Getting result of Activity as:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                btmapOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentFileUri.getPath(), btmapOptions);
                NewExpensesActivity.this.data.add(bm);
                imagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    compressedPath = ImageCompression.compressImage(currentFileUri.getPath());//ADDED 10018
                    galleryAddPic();
                    paths.add(compressedPath);//EDITED 10018

            }
        }
          }
```

But it throws Null Pointer Exception on delivering result
Log Cat:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.smarthumanoid.com/com.netdoers.com.ui.AddSxActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/SmartConsultant/20140217194718.jpg typ=image/jpeg (has extras) }} to activity {com.smarthumanoid.com/com.netdoers.com.ui.AddSxActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3865)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/SmartConsultant/20140217194718.jpg typ=image/jpeg (has extras) }} to activity {com.smarthumanoid.com/com.netdoers.com.ui.AddSxActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3488)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
... 13 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.netdoers.com.ui.AddSxActivity.onActivityResult(AddSxActivity.java:485)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5371)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3484)
... 14 more
```

Comment: where is `AddSxActivity.java:485`?

Comment: Check the code in AddSxActivity.java class inside onActivityResult. You are getting something null there. Also please post your whole activity code.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas : But the same application works fine in other phones. Just Sony causes these NPE. Please check edited SO.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan Line 485 : `bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentFileUri.getPath(), btmapOptions);` which works perfectly smooth in other phones didn't throws NPE. Putting it in try and catch block let's see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Camera Intent**

```
           try {
                Log.d("Main Activity", "Camera");

                String fileName = "temp.jpg";  
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
                mImageCaptureUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mImageCaptureUri);  

                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }
```

**onActivityResult**

```
       protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Main Activity", "On Activity Result");


    try {
        Uri selectedImage=null;

        if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK )
        {

            /* Log.d("Main Activity", "Camera");
              File fi = new File("/sdcard/tmp");
                 try {
                   selectedImage = Uri.parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), fi.getAbsolutePath(), null, null));
                     if (!fi.delete()) {
                         Log.i("logMarker", "Failed to delete " + fi);
                     }
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }*/
            selectedImage=mImageCaptureUri;
            /*          mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                       "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
            selectedImage=mImageCaptureUri;*/
        }
        if(selectedImage==null)
        {
            Log.d("Main Activity","Back");
            return;
        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Main Activity","Exception");
        return;
    }      
    return;

}
```

**selectedImage** is Uri of the captured Image and it is working fine in Sony mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are not giving any image name in `tempFile`, so that taken image can be saved with that name in SDCard.

Now, say, image name will be `123.jpg`....replace this

```
File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/ABC";);
```

with...

```
File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/ABC/123.jpg");
```

Comment: I'm already passing those variable as you describe only. Please see edited SO.